# Whitespace in front of a Token and rule splitting

Tags: parsing, antlr4

Thanks to answers here on stack overflow and some hours of work ;), my grammar is finally working as expected. There are just some minor issues or messy situations.

Here's my lexer definition:

```
lexer grammar dnpMDAuslagernLexer;

/*@members {
    public static final int COMMENTS = 1;
}*/

NL
    : [\r\n]
    ;

SUBHEADLINE
    : '##' (~[\r\n])+? '##'
    ;

HEADLINE
    : '#' ('\\#'|~[\r\n])+? '#'
    ;

LEAD
    : '###' (~[\r\n])+? '###'
    ;

SUBHEADING
    : '####' (~[\r\n])+? '####'
    ;

CAPTION
    : '#####' (~[\r\n])+? '#####'
    ;

LISTING
    : '~~~~~' .+? '~~~~~'
    ;

ELEMENTPATH
    : '[[[[[' (~[\r\n])+? ']]]]]'
    ;

LABELREF
    : '{##' (~[\r\n])+? '##}'
    ;

LABEL
    : '{#' (~[\r\n])+? '#}'
    ;

ITALIC
    : '*' (~[\r\n])+? '*'
    ;

SINGLE_COMMENT
    : '//' (~[\r\n])+ -> channel(1)
    ;

MULTI_COMMENT
    : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(1)
    ;

STAR
    : '*'
    ;

BRACE_OPEN
    : '{'
    ;

TEXT
    : (~[\r\n*{])+
    ;
```

And here's the definition for the parser:

```
parser grammar dnpMDAuslagernParser;

options { tokenVocab=dnpMDAuslagernLexer; }

dnpMD
    : head body
    ;

head
    : subheadline headline lead
    ;

subheadline
    : SUBHEADLINE NL+
    ;

headline
    : HEADLINE NL+
    ;

lead
    : LEAD
    ;

subheading
    : SUBHEADING
    ;

caption
    : CAPTION
    ;

listing
    : LISTING (NL listingPath)? (NL label)? NL caption
    ;

image
    : caption (NL label)? (NL imagePath)?
    ;

listingPath
    : ELEMENTPATH
    ;

imagePath
    : ELEMENTPATH
    ;

labelRef
    : LABELREF
    ;

label
    : LABEL
    ;

italic
    : ITALIC
    ;

singleComment
    : SINGLE_COMMENT
    ;

multiComment
    : MULTI_COMMENT
    ;

paragraph
    : TEXT? italic TEXT?
    | TEXT? STAR TEXT?
    | TEXT? labelRef TEXT?
    | TEXT? BRACE_OPEN TEXT?
    | TEXT? LABEL TEXT?
    | ELEMENTPATH
    | TEXT
    ;

newlines
    : NL+
    ;

body
    : bodyElements+
    ;

bodyElements
    : singleComment
    | multiComment
    | paragraph
    | subheading
    | listing
    | image
    | newlines
    ;
```

Looks like the member definition at the beginning of the lexer file isn't working in IntelliJ IDEA with the ANTLR4 plugin? Or am I missing something within the definition.

In the definitions of the headings I tried to allow beginning white space. But whatever I tried, the parsing process fails. I added a WS token [ \t]+ but when I add the WS token to the rules it gets ignored. Not quite sure what exactly fails.

But the bigger issue is the paragraph rule. There are many sub rules and they try to match elements of a paragraph. For example text or some other stuff.

I want to use this paragraph as a block so I know after the parsing process, that I can add a div oder something else around this paragraph. Because everything in this paragraph is a group of text. Paragraphs themselves are split up with newlines. That's working great.

But within the IntelliJ IDEA tree view I can see different paragraph entries within the tree. For example paragraph:1, paragraph:2 and so on. That because of the different rules.

Is there a way to have one paragraph entry within the parser tree and all containing text below it? Just split up by newlines?

I tried another rule as a top one of paragraph but that's not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different paragraph entries can be avoided with the following rule:

```
paragraph
    : (TEXT? italic TEXT?
    | TEXT? STAR TEXT?
    | TEXT? labelRef TEXT?
    | TEXT? BRACE_OPEN TEXT?
    | TEXT? LABEL TEXT?
    | ELEMENTPATH
    | TEXT
    )+
    ;
```

And the member definition, I want to use for different channels, shouldn't be done like that. The new channels definition is way better:

```
channels {
    COMMENTS
}
```

That's language independent and works very well.